# Setting up a send-only mail server

Tags: 14.04, mail-server, smtp

I'm trying to setup an easy mail server to support my "lost password" function in my website.

I'd like to know if Exim is good or not, or is there any better solution?

I would also like to know that it isn't easy to manage an smtp server (such as blocking junk mail, or being hacked, etc), does setting up a send-only mail server cause any security issues?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use _postfix_

Comment: Make sure that Exim4 is **only** listening on `localhost`, or you will be sending spam in no time.

Comment: Sending spam? I didn't get it.

Comment: @KKyang what Louis means is, that you don't want to accept mail from the outside, which would cause massive spam. You can either configure exim or postfix to only accept mail from localhost, or also use iptables to block smtp ports from outside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Simple example to setup postfix with satellite SMTP**

1. install postfix

   `sudo aptitude install postfix`
2. configure postfix

   `sudo vi /etc/postfix/smtp_auth`

   add **your** smtp authentication information in */etc/postfix/smtp_auth*:

   `smtp.foo.bar   user@host:password`

   and generate the postfix lookup table file (*/etc/postfix/smtp_auth.db*) using

   `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/smtp_auth`

   add the relayhost (outgoing smtp server e.g. smtp.foo.bar on port 587, depending your relay host info) information to */etc/postfix/main.cf*:

   `relayhost = [smtp.foo.bar]:587`

   add the following lines to */etc/postfix/main.cf* in order to enable smtp-auth for outgoing mails:

   `smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
   smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtp_auth
   smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous`
3. restart postfix

   `sudo service postfix restart`

Comment: So sasl is something like ssl that can avoid someone hijack the mail and read the content. Is that right?

Comment: @KKyang, yes SASL is Simple Authentication and Security Layer, a framework for authentication and data security in Internet protocols. You want to submit your SMTP authentication encrypted, and probably also the body of the e-mail. Therefore use SSL or TLS, when connecting to the remote SMTP relay host.

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to make sure my mail is sent secured, I should use both SASL and SSL?

Comment: @KKyang yes. SASL with TLS or SSL.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and here is how I did.
I created a gmail account for my daemon. I set up filters from gmail.com.

And I send my mail using 
http://iqjar.com/jar/sending-emails-from-the-raspberry-pi/

The guide is for raspberry pi but it will work as long as you use a debian or alike)

If you protected your server from bruteforce (fail2ban ?), it should be fine.

Comment: The website I setup is my university's lab website. I don't know if it's ok to use a personal account as an organization account. (If I graduate, I might want to take the account away.))

Comment: ssmtp does NOT verify the SSL/TLS certificate of the remote server on the current debian, ubuntu and redhat releases and also does NOT verify the hostname of the certificate. This is a major issue, as this effectively renders the encryption useless and your password is being transmitted alike to being plaintext and anyone can sniff it. ssmtp has had no active development since atleast 2009. So, if you care about the security of the email account you use for your servers outgoing emails, do NOT use ssmtp, but postfix (or something else) instead.