# Chkrootkit not producing a log file

Tags: 14.04, email, cron

This is the line from my crontab However, the log never gets sent to me..and when I check the log it is empty. I have tried  Chkrootkit from the terminal and it runs OK. What am I missing?

30 09 * * * root /usr/sbin/chkrootkit && cat /var/log/chkrootkit/log.today | mail -s "chkrootkit log for $(date)" xxx@gmail.com

I am using 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

A usual Desktop cannot send emails by default.

You need an email account somewhere and then for example **setup postfix with satellite SMTP** (see [Setting up a send-only mail server](https://askubuntu.com/a/457024/34298) )